# Python: how to parse rest log in?

Tags: python, parsing, logging

there is a rest log file that I would need to parse (using python panda) and extract some statistics on it:

```
2016-08-14 15:49:03,303 - RestLogger - INFO - rest_server::log_request:97 - REST call: <GET /v2/types/initiators/5?cluster-name=Virp-Cluster4 HTTP/1.1> with args {'cluster-name': ['Virp-Cluster4']}
2016-08-14 15:49:14,779 - RestLogger - INFO - rest_server::log_response:109 - REST response with code 200
2016-08-14 15:49:14,870 - RestLogger - INFO - rest_server::log_request:97 - REST call: <GET /v2/types/initiators/21?cluster-name=Vipr_Cluster3 HTTP/1.1> with args {'cluster-name': ['Vipr_Cluster3']}
2016-08-14 15:49:14,949 - RestLogger - INFO - rest_server::log_response:109 - REST response with code 200
2016-08-14 15:49:15,075 - RestLogger - INFO - rest_server::log_request:97 - REST call: <GET /v2/types/initiators/4?cluster-name=Virp-Cluster4 HTTP/1.1> with args {'cluster-name': ['Virp-Cluster4']}
2016-08-14 15:49:15,114 - RestLogger - INFO - rest_server::log_response:109 - REST response with code 200
```

I tried do this:

```
import pandas as pd
data_frame = pd.read_table("rest.log",sep=r"\n",engine='python')
```

as a result dataframe has 2 rows in it (should be 6 rows):

data_frame.all(0) returns the header
data_frame.all(1) returns the rest of the file's content

The expected result would be a regex that creates in panda a key,value pairs, for example if we look on the first line:

```
2016-08-14 15:49:03,303 - RestLogger - INFO - rest_server::log_request:97 - REST call: <GET /v2/types/initiators/5?cluster-name=Virp-Cluster4 HTTP/1.1> with args {'cluster-name': ['Virp-Cluster4']}
```

I would like panda to create for me the following hash:

- Date: "2016-08-14 15:49:03,303 (as a DateTime object)
- Method: GET
- URL: /v2/types/initiators/5?cluster-name=Virp-Cluster4
- http_version: HTTP/1.1
- arguments: {cluster-name: ['Virp-Cluster4']}

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the fields you need, exactly? Can you please give us an example output? To answer your question using regex (module `re`) is likely your best bet.

Comment: updated the original question post. using re sounds good. can you give example and how to store it in a variables that can be queried (like group by and so on)

Comment: Show us what you've already tried and we'll help you from there.

Comment: cool! edit the question again, please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a bunch of regular expressions to get what you want. Admittedly, those below aren't very robust regexes, by any means, but they *do* satisfy your base case. You might want to look into making them more fault-proof as you go forward, but this is a good start, I think.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

dates = []
methods = []
urls = []
http_versions = []
arguments = []

# use this to help with appending strings instead of the list objects returned by re.findall()
def try_except_index_catcher(lst):
    try:
        return lst[0]
    except IndexError:
        return None

with open('rest.log', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        date = line.split(' - ')
        method = re.findall(r'<\w+', line)
        url = re.findall(r'(/.+) HTTP', line)
        http_version = re.findall(r'HTTP/[0-9]+.[0-9]+', line)
        argument = re.findall(r'{.+}', line)

        dates.append(try_except_index_catcher(date))
        methods.append(try_except_index_catcher(method))
        urls.append(try_except_index_catcher(url))
        http_versions.append(try_except_index_catcher(http_version))
        arguments.append(try_except_index_catcher(argument))

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates, 'methods': methods, 'urls': urls, 'http_versions': http_versions, 'arguments': arguments})
```

You get this in `df`:

```
>>> df
                             arguments                    dates http_versions  \
0  {'cluster-name': ['Virp-Cluster4']}  2016-08-14 15:49:03,303      HTTP/1.1   
1                                 None  2016-08-14 15:49:14,779          None   
2  {'cluster-name': ['Vipr_Cluster3']}  2016-08-14 15:49:14,870      HTTP/1.1   
3                                 None  2016-08-14 15:49:14,949          None   
4  {'cluster-name': ['Virp-Cluster4']}  2016-08-14 15:49:15,075      HTTP/1.1   
5                                 None  2016-08-14 15:49:15,114          None   

  methods                                               urls  
0    <GET  /v2/types/initiators/5?cluster-name=Virp-Cluster4  
1    None                                               None  
2    <GET  /v2/types/initiators/21?cluster-name=Vipr_Clus...  
3    None                                               None  
4    <GET  /v2/types/initiators/4?cluster-name=Virp-Cluster4  
5    None                                               None
```